# Connection string fails in migration when stored as variable in Azure pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-sql-database, azure-yaml-pipelines

I'm executing migration using the following task. It works just as supposed to.

```
- task: SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1
  displayName: "App DB migration"
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: $(SrvConn)
    AuthenticationType: 'connectionString'
    ConnectionString: "Server=tcp:my-server.database.windows.net,1433;Database=my-db;Persist Security Info=False;User=the_user;Password=hash_puppy;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"
    deployType: 'SqlTask'
    SqlFile: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/migration/db_app.sql'
    IpDetectionMethod: 'AutoDetect'
```

I'd like, for security reasons, move the string a more secure location and the choice landed in using pipe variables (as discussed [in this blog, *secret value* section](https://dev.to/kenakamu/azure-devops-yaml-build-pipeline-how-to-use-variables-h8i)). After declaring one called `connstring` and assigning the exact value from the sample above, I run the updated task. However, it produces a range of errors.

Using `ConnectionString: '%CONNSTR%'`, `ConnectionString: $(CONSTRDEV)` or `ConnectionString: $(env:CONSTRDEV)`.

> ##[error]Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.Check out how to troubleshoot failures at https://aka.ms/sqlazuredeployreadme#troubleshooting

Using `ConnectionString: %CONNSTR%`.

> While scanning for the next token, find character that cannot start any token.

When I execute the below, the value is there, clearly available on the screen.

```
- pwsh: Write-Host ${env:CONSTRDEV}
```

I can't see what I'm doing incorrectly. Reading the docs gave me not much. Theoretically, it works (printout confirmation). However, the taks of migration fails regardless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that you originally had double quotation marks:

```
 ConnectionString: "Server=tcp:my-server.database
```

In the later one you used single quotation marks:

```
ConnectionString: '%CONNSTR%'
```

Also you should change your password

Comment: Oh, the password is fake, of course. I changed it in the posted sample. Thanks for reminding about it, though. One can get too involved and make a sloppy mistake. That said, I'm not still entirely clear on which of the three suggested versions (Bash, Batch, Powershell) of syntax I'm supposed to use and if it's supposed to be surrounded by apostrophes, quotes or nothing. It seems rather confusingly inconsistent to me. Or should I, perhaps, use quotes when entering the value of the variable?